# Gaussian probability distribution for a delta correlated random variable.

Tags: calculus, analysis, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, mathematical-physics

I read in a paper that I have a vector $\bf{x}$ such that
$$
⟨x_i(t)x_j(t′)⟩=δ_{ij}δ(t−t′)
$$
and the probability distribution for $\bf{x}$(t) is a Gaussian distribution and it can be written as:
$$
\exp\left[−\int_0^T dt\sum_{i,j}A_{i,j} x_i(t)x_j(t)\right]
$$
where $A_{i,j}$ is the variance matrix. Can someone please help how this Gaussian distribution is written; $\bf{especially ~why ~there ~is~ an~ integral~ in~ the~ exponent. }$

Comment: I am quite confused about the notation. It seems to me that $\mathbf{x}(t)$  is a continuous stochastic process, and the first definition seems to be implying that it is a white noise process, but then the use of the indexes $i, j$ confuses me.

Comment: It can be a white noise process. I think the indices $i$ and $j$ appear because $x$ is a vector and $x_i$ represents its components. The main question is why there is an integral in the exponent. Usually for the Gaussian probability distribution, there is no integral in the exponent.

Comment: The integral in the exponent could appear as follows: if all $x_i$ (or $x(t)$ for all t) were independent of each other and normally distributed, the joint probability distribution is the product of the individual probabilities. So one has
$P(\mathbf{x}(t)) \propto \prod_i  \exp{(-x_i(t_i)^2/2\sigma^2)} = \exp{(-\sum_i x_i(t_i)^2/2\sigma^2)}$ and in the continuous limit the sum becomes an integral. But I don't really get the sum over $i,j$ for the same time $t$ inside the integral.